de Broglie wavelength of electron
Why is the de Broglie wavelength of an electron $h/p$ since in Einstein's equation for energy of a particle, the rest mass of an electron is non-zero? What is the derivation of the wavelength in case of an electron, then?

I don't see any connection or contradiction between $m_e\ne0$ and $p= h/\lambda$. Where do you see one?  Also there is no derivation. It was a  guess by De Broglie that turned out to be correct.

This might help - The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum

The de Broglie equation is written as ($ \lambda ={\frac h p }$), where ($\lambda $) is the de Broglie wavelength, (h) is Planck's constant, and (p) is the particle's momentum.
FYI, de Broglie equation only works for bodies having rest mass.
In fact, the elementary conditions for de Broglie equations are:-
i. The body must be in motion.
ii. The body must have rest mass.
iii. Must be a microscopic particle.
So, it is favour of the equation that the rest mass of electron is non-zero.
Moreover, it's not possible to give you a derivation because the wavelength depends on momentum, which again depends on velocity of the electron. So, the wavelength would vary as the velocity of electron changes.
I hope that answers your question.

There is no requirement of the particle being massive.  If it is massless, then you cannot use the approximation $p=mv$ of course.

I didn't write massive . I meant that it has some rest mass. Let's edit that

In physics usage massive means "has non-zero  rest mass." It is is not meant to imply that the mass is large.

@mikestone The electron/proton has de Broglie wavelength of around 1 nm. Blue light has wavelength of 450 nm. Is this also the de Broglie wavelength of each photon of blue light?

@mikestone It's the same thing. But yh, srry, for overlooking the word massive.

Suppose we have a delocalised electron, or indeed any other particle, travelling freely through space, then the Schrodinger equation tells us the wavefunction is an infinite plane wave:
$$ \psi(x,t) = \exp(i(kx - \omega t)) \tag{1} $$
The momentum of the particle is given by the momentum operator:
$$ \hat{p} = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x} $$
If we apply this to our wavefunction (1) we get:
$$\begin{align}
 \hat{p\psi} &= -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi \\
         &= -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \exp(i(kx - \omega t)) \\
         &= -i\hbar(ik)\exp(i(kx - \omega t)) \\
         &= \hbar k \psi
\end{align} $$
So our wavefunction (1) is an eigenfunction of the momentum operator and the associated momentum is $p = \hbar k$, which is equal to $h/\lambda$. Then a trivial rearrangement gives us:
$$ \lambda = \frac{h}{p} $$
